# document.getElementById('pwMeter').style.display='none' not working as expected

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm trying to hide a div using the following method in a react web page. But it doesn't hide the element. I can't see any errors in the developer tools as well.

```
if(pw.length==0){
  document.getElementById('pwMeter').style.display='none'  
}
```

What is the problem here? Does React support this method?

Comment: not working is a poor problem description. what is happening instead? are there errors in your browser *developer* tools console to help you debug your code?

Comment: can you confirm that `pw.length==0` is true? can you confirm that any of the 2 lines of code you've shown is executed at all (debugging tip - console.log)

Comment: Why not set a property to true or false and then render the element based on the true or false value.  You are using React, so using the document seems to be defeating the purpose, kind of.  Can you post the React code, so we can get more context?

Comment: No it's not zero. Maybe that's the problem. I have set the null as default value of the pw.When value is set  to null does it take it as object with a length?

Comment: @noob try if(!pw)

Comment: I think you trying to hide div before it's render by reactjs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes with react you can do this , check this sample ref code for that

```
import { useState } from "react";

const TestFunction = (props) => {
  const [pw, setpw] = useState(["test"]);
  return (
    <div>
      <div
        id="pwMeter"
        style={pw && pw.length > 0 ? { display: "bock" } : { display: "none" }}
      >
        <p>test data</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default TestFunction;
```